# Способ изложения текста (индуктивный, дедуктивный)

Tags: риторика

К какому способу изложения относится данный текст?

*Листья мать-и-мачехи вначале развития опушены с обеих сторон мягкими белыми волосками. Затем с верхней стороны волоски спадают, листья становятся гладкими, кожистыми. Если лист потрогать ладонью, то с нижней стороны он кажется мягким и теплым (мать), а с верхней стороны – жестким и холодным (мачеха). Вот почему по-русски это растение называют именно так – мать-и-мачеха.*

Думаю, деуктивный, т. к. сперва раскрывается общая тема (
Листья мать-и-мачехи вначале развития опушены с обеих сторон мягкими белыми волосками), а потом (остальной текст) частное.

С другой стороны, можно ли считать первую часть общей? Напр. , если бы сперва описавалось бы, что  эта за растение, а потом давалась бы характеристика, сомнений не возникло бы.

Comment: Способ изложения материала относится к риторике, а не к стилистике (я изменил метку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте попробуем вместе разобраться (я до этого знал только о дедуктивном методе Шерлока Холмса).

[Способы изложения материала](https://studfiles.net/preview/6018977/page:4/)

**Дедуктивный** способ – изложение материала от общего к частному (от тезиса к его доказательствам). Это способ поиска подтверждений высказанному ранее обобщению. Например:

Кто художество наше любит, а мастера презирает, тот лжет. Кто действительно мастерство народное любит, любит и художника. А кто спесивится перед нашим братом, не любит искусства нашего, кто оскорбляет художника – искусство его оскорбляет.

**Индуктивный** способ – изложение материала от частного к общему, от фактов к некоторой гипотезе, способ предвосхищения основания. Например:

В одном конце залы – широкая лестница... и по обеим ее сторонам высокие двери с прибитыми над ними оленьими головами – они ведут в бильярдную, библиотеку, большую желтую залу и в гостиные. На втором этаже, по меньшей мере, двадцать спален. ... Наша классная помещается на втором этаже, и из нее одна дверь ведет в мою спальню, а другая в спальню девиц. Затем идут апартаменты мистера Питта – мистера Кроули, как его здесь называют, – старшего сына, и покои мистера Родона Кроули. Словом, недостатка в помещении тут нет, могу тебя уверить! Мне кажется, что в этом доме можно было бы разместить все население Рассел-сквер, да и то осталось бы место»

---

Разница состоит в том, что дедуктивный способ идет от тезиса к его доказательствам, а индуктивный - наоборот. У Вас тезис (растение называют именно так – мать-и-мачеха) стоит в конце. А сначала - факты, которые подводят Вас к тезису, на основании этих фактов становится понятно, почему именно мать-и-мачеха. Вывод: использован **индуктивный** способ. Кстати, я тоже использовал его в своем ответе.

Comment: Спасибо. Я еще один вопрос задам. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.